# How to check if an object exists inside a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am using Python to implement an Earley Parser that has Context Free rules defined as follows:

```
class Rule:
    def __init__(self,string,i,j,dot):
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 0
        self.dot = 0
        string = string.split('->')
        self.lhs = string[0].strip()
        self.rhs1 = string[1].strip()
        self.rhs = []
        self.rhs1 = self.rhs1.split(' ')
        for word in self.rhs1:
            if word.strip()!= '':
                self.rhs.append(word)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.i == other.i:
            if self.j == other.j:
                if self.dot == other.dot:
                    if self.lhs == other.lhs:
                        if self.rhs == other.rhs:
                            return True
        return False
```

To check whether an object of class `Rule` exists within a chart array or not, I have used the following:

```
def enqueue(self, entry, state):
    if state in self.chart[entry]:
        return None
    else:
        self.chart[entry].append(state)
```

where chart is an array that is supposed to contain lists of objects of class `Rule`:

```
def __init__(self, words):
    self.chart = [[] for i in range(len(words))]
```

Further I check whether a rule exists as that in the `chart[entry]` as follows (and if it does not exist, then simply append):

```
def enqueue(self, entry, state):
    if state in self.chart[entry]:
        return None
    else:
        self.chart[entry].append(state)
```

However this gives me an error  as

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not classobj
```

To circumvent this, I even declared an `__eq__` function in the class itself but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `self.chart[entry]` is a list? From the error message, it seems like `self.chart[entry]` is a string. What shows up if you do `print type(self.chart[entry])` at the beginning of `enqueue`?

Comment: Change `class rule:` to `class Rule(object):`

Comment: @All, edited the code above.

Comment: @Kevin It says type<'list'>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your object has only a title attribute which is relevant for equality, you have to implement the `__eq__` method as follows:

```
class YourObject:
    [...]
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.title == other.title
```

Of course if you have more attributes that are relevant for equality, you must include those as well. You might also consider implementing `__ne__` and `__cmp__` for consistent behaviour.